# Apache2 logs missing in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

My Ec2 instance configured with apache2 was running fine and all of a sudden web-server stopped serving pages. I checked all the logs but it didn't help or may i am missing something here. Below are the error logs of apache2

```
[Mon Jan 12 18:15:49 2015] [error] [client 76.164.202.114] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11
[Mon Jan 12 18:15:49 2015] [error] [client 76.164.202.114] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:29 2015] [error] [client 114.124.39.172] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: link in /data/html/article_emailconfig.php on line 37
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:29 2015] [error] [client 114.124.39.172] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: link in /data/html/article_emailconfig.php on line 37
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:46 2015] [error] [client 5.44.217.87] File does not exist: /data/html/old
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:56 2015] [error] [client 114.124.39.172] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: link in /data/html/article_emailconfig.php on line 37
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:56 2015] [error] [client 114.124.39.172] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: urlid in /data/html/friend.php on line 67
[Mon Jan 12 18:16:56 2015] [error] [client 114.124.39.172] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: link in /data/html/article_emailconfig.php on line 37
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:27 2015] [error] [client 188.165.15.117] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:27 2015] [error] [client 188.165.15.117] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:36 2015] [error] [client 120.40.144.203] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:36 2015] [error] [client 120.40.144.203] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:39 2015] [error] [client 12.218.42.6] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11, referer: http://search.pch.com/frontpagesearch?q=shovavim
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:39 2015] [error] [client 12.218.42.6] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18, referer: http://search.pch.com/frontpagesearch?q=shovavim
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:45 2015] [error] [client 66.249.67.27] script '/data/html/go.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:57 2015] [error] [client 46.165.222.7] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11
[Mon Jan 12 18:17:57 2015] [error] [client 46.165.222.7] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18
[Mon Jan 12 18:18:31 2015] [error] [client 66.249.67.35] script '/data/html/go.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 18:18:36 2015] [error] [client 171.113.243.6] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: categoryname in /data/html/judaism.php on line 11
[Mon Jan 12 18:18:36 2015] [error] [client 171.113.243.6] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /data/html/judaism.php on line 18
[Mon Jan 12 19:05:14 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 12 19:05:33 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 19:05:33 2015] [error] [client 87.253.132.202] script '/data/html/virtualjerusalem_rss.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 19:05:33 2015] [error] [client 87.253.132.202] script '/data/html/virtualjerusalem_rss.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 19:05:51 2015] [error] [client 66.249.67.27] script '/data/html/food/MOVED/Soup_minestrone.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 19:06:09 2015] [error] [client 87.253.132.203] script '/data/html/virtualjerusalem_rss.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 19:06:10 2015] [error] [client 87.253.132.203] script '/data/html/virtualjerusalem_rss.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 12 19:06:10 2015] [error] [client 66.249.67.133] script '/data/html/virtualjerusalem_rss.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I have lost logs of almost 45-47 Minutes. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your server was down for those 45 minutes.
Try to restart your server:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If the problem persists, try a full reboot.

If the problem is gone, apache might have crashed - there was a bug in apache 2.2 (very old, resolved years ago https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=398223)

If the problem persists,
Do you have a system image from before the collapse? If so, comparison of configuration files may tell us if something was tempered with your server. If you have an SSH server there, check

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

there may be other files:

```
/var/log/auth.log.1
/var/log/auth.log.2.tgz etc
```

find the one that contains the timeframe of interest and see for anything suspicious there.

Comment: Thanks That helped a lot. It was ftp hack attempt. Thanks for the support.

Comment: if you don't need ftp services it's a good idea to disable ftp server. Same goes for other services you don't need.
A STRONG advice - if you are not 100% sure the hacking failed, clear up the server completely and make a clean install. Also install tripwire - an intrusion detection tool.